# Properly using c-code libs in Xcode to allow multi-platforms

Tags: ios, xcode, cross-platform

I have a c library of astronomical code that I'd like to make use of in several formats - a command line that reads and writes files, an iOS app with graphical output, etc.

Ideally I'd like to be able to leave the code in a format that would allow the most basic version (the CLI's) to be cross-compiled on other platforms, while remaining editable within Xcode for the iOS versions - if such a thing is possible.

Does anyone have a good guide on how to arrange projects in Xcode in order to make them easier to move between different targets like this, while avoiding platform lock-in as much as possible?